# Custom tick values on a c3.js chart

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I'm trying to make an horizontal bar chart using c3.js , I would like to put the name of the axis by myself for that I use :

```
tick: {

                        count: 6,
                        format: function () {
                            var label1 = ["[-25 ans]", "[25-29 ans]","[30-34 ans]", "[25-29 ans]","[30-34 ans]","[35-39 ans]"];
                            for (var i in label1){
                                return (label1[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

but as a result I only get [-25 ans] for all the ticks and in the IDE it says "for statement doesn't loop"

Am I doing something wrong ? How can I correct that ?
Thanks

Comment: what do you want that for loop to do?

Comment: if you use `return` in the loop it will exit the loop on the first loop

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I want to rename the ticks of the axis

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald what can I use instead of return to rename the axis ?

Comment: What do you mean by "put the name of the axis by myself?"  What is your desired output?

Comment: @IanMcLaird if you look at the example is http://c3js.org/samples/axes_rotated.html , you'll find that the bar chart axis has the values [0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ] , I want to replace that with pther values

Comment: DO NOT use a for...in loop for arrays. They're supposed to only be used for object dictionaries.

Comment: @ndugger then what should I use ?

Comment: @Jean a regular for loop; `for (let i = 0; i < whatever; i++) { ... }` or if your browser supports it, a for...of loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [axis.x.tick.values](http://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-x-tick-values)

```
tick: {
  values: ["[-25 ans]", "[25-29 ans]","[30-34 ans]", "[25-29 ans]","[30-34 ans]","[35-39 ans]"]
}
```

[Example](http://c3js.org/samples/axes_x_tick_values.html)